# css flex div height issue - why the huge space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I have a two column, multiple row flex layout

I want to lose the empty space below the text, I dont want this huge gap below the text until the div ends and the the next row begins.

How can I do this without setting a fixed height?

(best explained through this image)

[image]

```css
.col-xs,
.col-sm {
  position: relative;
}

.col-sm {
  float: left;
}

.col-sm {
  width: 91.66667%;
}

.flex-grid-component {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-grid-component .flex-grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-width: 1.5vw;
}

.property-item-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.property-item-container .property-details {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="col-xs col-sm">
    <div class="flex-grid-component">

      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like there's a `height: 100%` present somewhere. Try adding `height: auto` to the flex container.

Comment: Or add `align-content: flex-start` to flex parent. Wrapping flex children's height is shared among the parent height, equally, as `align-content` defaults to `stretch`.

Comment: If you can't demonstrate it, **it didn't happen**. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean? I include the code that demonstrates it, this html code I open in my Chrome browser and it demonstrate it, I even included a image of what it looks like in my Chrome browser to demonstrate it

Comment: @Michael_B thanks, that actually solved the problem in my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you need to remove `height: 100%;` from `.property-item-container` . I already correct this below. This is not a browser specific problem.

```css
  .col-xs,
.col-sm {
  position: relative;
}

.col-sm {
  float: left;
}

.col-sm {
  width: 91.66667%;
}

.flex-grid-component {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-grid-component .flex-grid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-width: 1.5vw;
}

.property-item-container {
  width: 100%;

  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.property-item-container .property-details {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs col-sm">
    <div class="flex-grid-component">

      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="property-item-container">
          <div class="property-details">
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a malesuada lorem, ut gravida metus. Cras elementum vitae mi a ornare. Curabitur eget congue diam, at dictum ante.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No, that is not it in the provided sample. Restore the `height: 100%;` in your sample and you'll see it still works.

Comment: listen  you haven't  provide any height in parents that's why it's taking so much of height in browser.

Comment: First off, I'm not the one who asked, second, if not a height is given, flex row items will collapse to their content, so when saying that it is the reason, you need to read up on how Flexbox works.